# How to copy the file with local settings to a chosen location by Folder Picker as a backup? UWP C#

Tags: c#, file, uwp, settings

I have an Universal Windows Platform application that saves some values to its local settings and then loads them.

**Is it possible to copy the settings.dat file in the app's folder and save it somewhere else?**

**If it is, how to do it?**

Comment: Could you please tell me why you want to back up the settings.dat file? Usually, there is no need to back up local settings files. If you want to back up some data, you could save data to a file in Local Folder, and then copy the file to another location.

Comment: I would want to back up the settings.dat in a folder chosen by the user in a Folder Picker, so that the user can make a backup to a specified location on a click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the following code as a sample:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var parent =await folder.GetParentAsync();
    var settingFolder =await parent.GetFolderAsync("Settings");
    if(settingFolder!=null)
    {
        var datFile=await settingFolder.GetFileAsync("settings.dat");
        if(datFile!=null)
        {
            await datFile.CopyAsync(folder);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to add the [broadFileSystemAccess capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) in manifest and enable the **File system** option for your app in **Settings** panel.